# Flutter-GetX; Update list in item of list

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, flutter-getx

I'm having a problem, I have a list let say (ListOne) and each item has a list let say (ListTwo), when I enter an item into ListOne, `ListView.builder`/`ListView.separated` for ListOne it works while when I enter an item into ListTwo `ListView.builder`/`ListView.separated` for ListTwo it doesn't it works, I've tried using the `Obx` Widget but it doesn't work

this is my `LisView` for ListOne

```
ListView.separated(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         var _listOneItem = controller.listOne.elementAt(index);
         return ListOneItemWidget(item: __listOneItem);
    },
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10.0),
    itemCount: controller.listOne.length,
),
```

and this is my `ListView` for ListTwo

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var _listTwoItem = listOneItem.ListTwo.elementAt(index);
        return ListTwoItemWidget(item: _listTwoItem);
    },
    itemCount: listOneItem.ListTwo.length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) library then wrap the **ListView.builder()/ListView.separated()** with **Obx()** widget and try having the `listOne` and `listTwo` as **Observable** fields which you will be using in **Obx()** method. Make sure you use **Observable** fields in **Obx()** in the first level of its usage rather than using in the nested children widgets.

for Eg:
Proper Usage would be -

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';


List<dynamic> listOne = List.empty(growable : true).obs;
Obx(()
{
  var list = listOne.toList(growable:true);
  return ListView.builder();
}
);
```